# VBA checkbox (2 times to check)

Tags: excel, vba

I'm working with VBA in Excel 2007.

When I click on my checkbox, I have to do it 2 times before the check mark appears. I have no idea what can cause that. Can somebody help me?

Comment: Before you click it the first time, is the checkbox filled with grey hatching?

Comment: Also is it a Form Control or an ActiveX Control?

Answer (score 0):

This behaviour is normal when the Excel application is not the active one on your screen (= doesn't have the focus)

- the first click is to activate the Excel application window
- the second click is to work inside the application.

This applies to Form or ActiveX checkboxes embedded a sheet, it even happens when you want to select a certain cell (say C2) ... when Excel was inactive, the first click (into C3) activates the application and shows the cursor at its previous location (say B3), second click will move cursor to C3.

User forms behave a bit different. Even when they have no focus at first, once you click into a checkbox inside the user form, it activates AND processes the checkbox - except if you trick it out by an event trigger (there are a few that could come in here)